# Mapbox Navigation Crashes on clicking Start Navigation

Tags: mapbox

I followed the instruction from example"Build a navigation app for Android" (October 17th 2018)

https://www.mapbox.com/help/android-navigation-sdk/#install-the-navigation-sdk

Using the final code provided at the bottom of the example.

What is causing the app to crash when I select start Navigation?

```
 package media.icarusaerial.assetnavigator;


    import java.util.List;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    // classes needed to initialize map
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
    // classes needed to add location layer
    import com.mapbox.geojson.Point;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.locationlayer.LocationLayerPlugin;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.locationlayer.modes.CameraMode;
    import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncherOptions;
    import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngine;
    import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEnginePriority;
    import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProvider;
    import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineListener;
    import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener;
    import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager;
    // classes needed to add a marker
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.Marker;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.MarkerOptions;
    // classes to calculate a route
    import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.route.NavigationMapRoute;
    import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.navigation.NavigationRoute;
    import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsResponse;
    import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsRoute;
    import retrofit2.Call;
    import retrofit2.Callback;
    import retrofit2.Response;
    import android.util.Log;
    // classes needed to launch navigation UI
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncher;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, MapboxMap.OnMapClickListener, LocationEngineListener, PermissionsListener {
        private MapView mapView;
        // variables for adding location layer
        private MapboxMap mapboxMap;
        private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
        private LocationLayerPlugin locationLayerPlugin;
        private LocationEngine locationEngine;
        private Location originLocation;
        // variables for adding a marker
        private Marker destinationMarker;
        private LatLng originCoord;
        private LatLng destinationCoord;
        // variables for calculating and drawing a route
        private Point originPosition;
        private Point destinationPosition;
        private DirectionsRoute currentRoute;
        private static final String TAG = "DirectionsActivity";
        private NavigationMapRoute navigationMapRoute;
        private Button button;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        };

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
            this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
            enableLocationPlugin();
            originCoord = new LatLng(originLocation.getLatitude(), originLocation.getLongitude());
            mapboxMap.addOnMapClickListener(this);
            button = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean simulateRoute = true;
                    NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
                            .directionsRoute(currentRoute)
                            .shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute)
                            .build();
                    // Call this method with Context from within an Activity
                    NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(MainActivity.this, options);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point){
            if (destinationMarker != null) {
                mapboxMap.removeMarker(destinationMarker);
            }
            destinationCoord = point;
            destinationMarker = mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(destinationCoord)
            );
            destinationPosition = Point.fromLngLat(destinationCoord.getLongitude(), destinationCoord.getLatitude());
            originPosition = Point.fromLngLat(originCoord.getLongitude(), originCoord.getLatitude());
            getRoute(originPosition, destinationPosition);
            button.setEnabled(true);
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.mapboxBlue);
        }

        private void getRoute(Point origin, Point destination) {
            NavigationRoute.builder(this)
                    .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
                    .origin(origin)
                    .destination(destination)
                    .build()
                    .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
                            // You can get the generic HTTP info about the response
                            Log.d(TAG, "Response code: " + response.code());
                            if (response.body() == null) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "No routes found, make sure you set the right user and access token.");
                                return;
                            } else if (response.body().routes().size() < 1) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "No routes found");
                                return;
                            }

                            currentRoute = response.body().routes().get(0);

                            // Draw the route on the map
                            if (navigationMapRoute != null) {
                                navigationMapRoute.removeRoute();
                            } else {
                                navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, mapboxMap, R.style.NavigationMapRoute);
                            }
                            navigationMapRoute.addRoute(currentRoute);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + throwable.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
        }
        @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
        private void enableLocationPlugin() {
            // Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
            if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {
                initializeLocationEngine();
                // Create an instance of the plugin. Adding in LocationLayerOptions is also an optional
                // parameter
                LocationLayerPlugin locationLayerPlugin = new LocationLayerPlugin(mapView, mapboxMap);

                // Set the plugin's camera mode
                locationLayerPlugin.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);
                getLifecycle().addObserver(locationLayerPlugin);
            } else {
                permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
                permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
        private void initializeLocationEngine() {
            LocationEngineProvider locationEngineProvider = new LocationEngineProvider(this);
            locationEngine = locationEngineProvider.obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable();
            locationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationEngine.activate();

            Location lastLocation = locationEngine.getLastLocation();
            if (lastLocation != null) {
                originLocation = lastLocation;
            } else {
                locationEngine.addLocationEngineListener(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        @Override
        public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.user_location_permission_explanation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
            if (granted) {
                enableLocationPlugin();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.user_location_permission_not_granted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            mapView.onStart();
            if (locationLayerPlugin != null) {
                locationLayerPlugin.onStart();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mapView.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            mapView.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            mapView.onStop();
            if (locationLayerPlugin != null) {
                locationLayerPlugin.onStart();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mapView.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLowMemory() {
            super.onLowMemory();
            mapView.onLowMemory();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        }
    }
```

**build.gradle**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "media.icarusaerial.assetnavigator"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

        //Mapbox dependencies
        implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.6.0'
        implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.10'
        implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.21.0'
        implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.21.0'


    }
```

**styles.xml**

```
    <resources>

        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        </style>

        <style name="NavigationMapRoute">
            <!-- Colors -->
            <item name="routeColor">@color/mapboxBlue</item>
            <item name="routeModerateCongestionColor">@color/mapboxYellow</item>
            <item name="routeSevereCongestionColor">@color/mapboxPink</item>
            <item name="routeShieldColor">@color/mapboxWhite</item>
            <!-- Scales -->
            <item name="routeScale">1.0</item>
        </style>

        <style name="NavigationView" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <item name="navigationViewPrimary">@color/mapboxWhite</item>
            <item name="navigationViewSecondary">@color/mapboxBlue</item>
            <item name="navigationViewAccent">@color/mapboxPink</item>
        </style>



    </resources>
```

**color.xml**

```
 <color name="colorPrimary">#4264fb</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#4264fb</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#4264fb</color>

    <color name="mapboxWhite">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="mapboxBlue">#4264fb</color>
    <color name="mapboxGrayLight">#c6d2e1</color>

    <color name="mapboxPink">#ee4e8b</color>
    <color name="mapboxYellow">#d9d838</color>
    <color name="mapboxRed">#b43b71</color>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help from Mapbox support (Josh Eru) notified me the latest Mapbox SDK 6.6.0 eliminated the need for the LocationLayerPlugin. Once I used the dependencies below I was able to run the "Start Navigation" button.

```
//Mapbox dependencies
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.5.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.21.0'
```